# Raspberry Pi 3B not booting anymore.How to update firmwire?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, firmware

I have a RPi 3b in my stack. Suddenly it stopped working correctly and after another OS flash it was dead. Now is there a way to revive it?

Comment: Find what died.  Maybe just that sd is bad?

Comment: The Sdcard is ok. tested on pi4. But for pi 3 it is not working.

Comment: how do you know that it is dead?

Comment: Because I tried everything already. Is there a way to get into the firmwire?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the power supply? They are the first to fail.

If it suddenly stopped working, likely it's a hardware problem.